# I'm trying to generate the apk of my application using EXPO

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

can someone help me to solve these problems? I've done several installations and it doesn't solve the problems, sometimes it even increases.

I'm using the command "eas build -p android --profile preview"

build errors

[image: 1]

package.json

[image: 2]

I already did some research to see if anyone had any problems, then I ran the install, update command and it only increased the errors. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try running ```expo doctor --fix-dependencies``` this should fi some of your issues

Comment: now i have problema in gradlew